# I am unable to center content in a grid item with justify-content: center; or justify-items: center. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center text within a grid-item horizontally with either justify-content: center or justify-items: center, but it's not working. What am I doing wrong? Please see my code below:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 820px;
  height: 520px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 800px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 300px;
  gap: 20px 0;
  border: #84A98C 20px solid;
  background: #84A98C;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.grid-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #354F52;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  /* padding: 10px; */
}
```

```html
<article>
  <p class="test-instructions">Retype the text below exactly as you see it without any errors. You will be timed, Good Luck!</p>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="grid-item-one grid-items">
      <p>In the world of serverless applications, Webiny is becoming a popular way to adopt the serverless approach of building applications by providing handy tools that developers can build their apps upon. In this article, we will look into what Webiny
        is and try out the headless CMS as a data source for a Gatsby blog application.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item-two grid-items"></div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Are more details needed to figure out this question?

Comment: `justify-content` is a flex property not a grid property. it has no influence with the use of `display: grid`.

Comment: the textblock btw. is centered. Its just fills up the entire container space. The space at the right side that make it appear that it is not centered is because of the text-wrap in combination that the entire container width is filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont work, because `p` is the only child of `.grid-items` and would take the entire width.

If you want to see any effect of it getting aligned horizontally, you would have to give it some flex-basis/width. Because justify-content aligns the element based on the **remaining** space available. If your `p` takes the entire width, there wont be any space left and it wont have any effect.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  width: 820px;
  height: 520px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  grid-template-columns: 800px;
  grid-template-rows: 200px 300px;
  gap: 20px 0;
  border: #84A98C 20px solid;
  background: #84A98C;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

.grid-items {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #354F52;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 15px;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <article>
      <p class="test-instructions">Retype the text below exactly as you see it without any errors.
        You will be timed, Good Luck!</p>
      <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item-one grid-items">
          <p>In the world of serverless applications, Webiny is becoming a popular way to adopt
            the
            serverless approach of building applications by providing handy tools that developers
            can build their apps upon.
            In this article, we will look into what Webiny is and try out the headless CMS as a
            data source for a Gatsby
            blog application.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item-two grid-items"></div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: @Sam Glad to help. If this solved your issue, please mark it as answer..

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align:center` in p tag of `grid-items` class

as

`.grid-items p{ text-align: center; }`

Working code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .grid-container {
            display: grid;
            width: 820px;
            height: 520px;
            justify-content: center;
            margin: auto;
            grid-template-columns: 800px;
            grid-template-rows: 200px 300px;
            gap: 20px 0;
            border: #84A98C 20px solid;
            background: #84A98C;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }

        .grid-items span {
            display: block;
            width: 95%;
            margin: auto;

        }

        .grid-items {
            display: flex;
            justify-items: center;
            align-items: center;
            background: #354F52;
            color: white;
            border-radius: 25px;

        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <article>
        <p class="test-instructions">Retype the text below exactly as you see it without any errors.
            You will be timed, Good Luck!</p>
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="grid-item-one grid-items">
                <span>
                    <span style="text-align: left;">
                        In the world of serverless applications, Webiny is becoming a popular way to adopt
                        the serverless approach of building applications by providing handy tools that developers
                        can build their apps upon. In this article, we will look into what Webiny is and try out the
                        headless CMS as a data source for a Gatsby
                        blog application.
                        </span>
                        </span>
            </div>
            <div class="grid-item-two grid-items"></div>
        </div>
    </article>
    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the text to have left justification while being centered in the middle of the green background at the same time. How do I do that?

Comment: I am not getting your point.made some changes in above code check it.